# Sum values of 1 if the column names are less and greater than row value in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, sum

I have a dataset consisting of many columns with the names of the day of the year, starting at 1 ending at 305. At the same time, I have a column containing the threshold for when to sum it up.
I want to sum up all the values equals 1, within the range of column names > threshold - 10 and threshold.

So eventually it would be:

sum if colname > threshold - 30 and colname < threshold and values == 1.

I have tried the following

```r
t <- rowSums(x[colnames(x[,1:ncol(x)]) > x$threshold - 30 & 
       colnames(x[, 1:ncol(x)]) < x$threshold, ] == 1)
```

But this does not sum up the values with the range I am asking for per row.

How do I achieve this in R?

Test data:

```r
x <- data.frame(ID = seq(1,100,1), '1' = seq(1,100,1), 
                                   '2' = seq(1,100,1), 
                                   '3' = seq(1,100,1), 
                                   '4' = seq(1,100,1), 
                                   '5' = seq(1,100,1), 
                                   '6' = seq(1,100,1), 
                                   '7' = seq(1,100,1), 
                 threshold = seq(1,100,1))

t <- rowSums(x[colnames(x[,1:ncol(x)]) > x$threshold - 30 & 
       colnames(x[,1:ncol(x)]) < x$threshold, ] == 1)
```

Comment: This is an awkward data structure for this operation. If you pivoted your data to a long format with 1 column for ID, one column for threshold, one column for day-of-year, and one column for your measure, then this would be a pretty standard rolling sum by group.